# Getting ExceptionInInitializerError due to UnsatisfiedLinkError for Android NDK

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk

When I use NDK + Android + JNI + OPENCV4ANDROID(2.4.2) I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1312]:  2586 cannot locate '_ZN2cv3Mat8copySizeERKS0_'...
```

I couldn't find anything useful when I searched.

Here's the logcat:

```
04-10 12:05:19.960: E/AndroidRuntime(11567): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-10 12:05:19.960: E/AndroidRuntime(11567): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
04-10 12:05:19.960: E/AndroidRuntime(11567):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl>(Native Method)
04-10 12:05:19.960: E/AndroidRuntime(11567):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
04-10 12:05:19.960: E/AndroidRuntime(11567):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
04-10 12:05:19.960: E/AndroidRuntime(11567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1565)
04-10 12:05:19.960: E/AndroidRuntime(11567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
04-10 12:05:19.960: E/AndroidRuntime(11567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-10 12:05:19.960: E/AndroidRuntime(11567):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
04-10 12:05:19.960: E/AndroidRuntime(11567):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-10 12:05:19.960: E/AndroidRuntime(11567):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-10 12:05:19.960: E/AndroidRuntime(11567):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3691)
04-10 12:05:19.960: E/AndroidRuntime(11567):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-10 12:05:19.960: E/AndroidRuntime(11567):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-10 12:05:19.960: E/AndroidRuntime(11567):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:907)
04-10 12:05:19.960: E/AndroidRuntime(11567):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
04-10 12:05:19.960: E/AndroidRuntime(11567):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-10 12:05:19.960: E/AndroidRuntime(11567): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1312]:  2586 cannot locate '_ZN2cv3Mat8copySizeERKS0_'...
04-10 12:05:19.960: E/AndroidRuntime(11567):    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:434)
04-10 12:05:19.960: E/AndroidRuntime(11567):    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
04-10 12:05:19.960: E/AndroidRuntime(11567):    at com.amani.main.chooser.<clinit>(chooser.java:139)
04-10 12:05:19.960: E/AndroidRuntime(11567):    ... 15 more
```

Why am I getting an `UnsatisfiedLinkError`?

Comment: Subject should be related Question .!!

Comment: Calm down Nirav. He/she is obviously new. Yes it's mandatory to read the rules and etiquette before posting but, i'm sure we've all been there at some point.

Comment: The error means that the library you've added hasn't loaded. Could you post some code? Around the likes of line 139.

Comment: line139:System.loadLibrary("Mark"); Mark is the name of lib.

Comment: I creed 3 class, when I use 3 class in JNI, le program work with the error. Here are 3 line:                       PatternDetector     m_patternDetector;            Pattern             pattern;                      PatternTrackingInfo m_patternInfo;  Thank you very much and forgive me my poor English.

Comment: Thank you for Subby and sorry for Nirav. My English is just so-so. I have tried my best edit the text, but i can not arrive it. Thank you for thegrinner to help me edit it, Thank you very much.